# Is there a TeX-native way to generate a readable graph from an adjacency matrix?

Tags: automation, graphs

#### related questions

- This question goes the opposite way from the conversion I would like: [Matrix from graph description](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81932/matrix-from-graph-description)
- This question is almost what I want, but the vertex coordinates are manually specified: [How to plot a graph from its adjacency matrix (coordinates manually specified)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164895/how-to-plot-a-graph-from-its-adjacency-matrix)

#### goal

I would like to go from either an adjacency matrix or list of edge pairs to a human-readable graph diagram that fits on a page, i.e. as in the example from the first question, from this:

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 5)
(2, 1)
(2, 3)
(2, 5)
(3, 2)
(3, 4)
(4, 3)
(4, 5)
(4, 6)
(5, 1)
(5, 2)
(5, 4)
(6, 4)
```

to this:

[image: desired graph]

I'm not particular about the formatting, or node placement, apart from general things like color and maybe bounding box--I would just like to keep it entirely contained inside a TeX document (as opposed to relying on an external file from GraphViz etc.).

Is there an existing solution for this? If not, where do I start?

Comment: You can do this pretty much built-in using TikZ and LuaTeX.

Comment: Are any of [these differences](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex) between LuaTeX and XeTeX going to break existing documents out of the box? I'm coming from XeTeX which I rely on constantly for Unicode/international support.

Comment: I can't say.  I know that LuaTeX isn't yet stable enough (IMHO) for *archival* documents, but from what I've heard it is very much stable enough for general use.  YMMV.

Comment: The [sagetex package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/) uses a CAS that [has lots of support for graph theory](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/prep/Quickstarts/Graphs-and-Discrete.html#graph-theory). You'd need to install Sage on your computer or process LaTeX with a free [SageMath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) account. You can experiment with Sage code for graphs using a [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

Comment: That's definitely my fallback and I have used sagetex before, but it's quite a heavy dependency even if it can be reached from within a TeX document.

Comment: you could also code in you favourite language a program to take in stdin an adjacency matrix as input and stdout an image, and then find a tex package to streamline your calls from LaTeX to your program. Python has great graphs libraries with easy image generation features, you may take a look if you know a bit of Python.

Comment: Will you be willing to accept inlined-graphviz?

Comment: @einpoklum That's probably the leanest strategy, isn't it?