# decorating with tkz-berge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, graphs, tkz-collection

In my continuing [quest to draw circles and lines willy-nilly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201765/is-there-a-tex-native-way-to-generate-a-readable-graph-from-an-adjacency-matrix), I've made the following use of tkz-berge:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,mindmap}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{160,180,200}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{110,130,150}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[concept, outer sep=0pt, color=lightblue, every node/.style={circle,fill={lightblue}},
                    every path/.style={circle connection bar, fill=darkblue}]
  \SetVertexNoLabel
  \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
    \grEmptyCycle[RA=2/sin(60)]{5}
  \end{scope}
  \AssignVertexLabel{a}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \Edges(a0,a2)
  \Edges(a3,a1)
  \Edges(a4,a0,a3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The goal is to duplicate the style seen in Till Tantau's 2012 talk, without dragging in LuaTeX:

[image: till's example]

Unfortunately, what the above code generates is this:

[image: current result]

If `\AssignVertexLabel` is commented out, the `circle connection bar` edges are properly positioned, but the node formatting as specified is not completely applied. No arguments for `path/.style={color=}` or `fill=` properly shade the edges; I seem to have a choice of black or nothing.

Is there a way to get this kind of style control while maintaining the relative ease of tkz-berge?

Comment: Great, I wanted to reproduce the example but with LuaLaTex and you provided enough details for me to get the job done. TY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to work around is to define `every node style` as such (where the inner sep=xx affects the filled area while the line width adjust the line thickness one desires)

```
every node/.style= {circle,fill={lightblue},draw=black,line width=1pt,inner sep=2.7pt}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,mindmap}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{160,180,200}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{110,130,150}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[concept, outer sep=0pt, color=lightblue, 
every node/.style= {circle,fill={lightblue},draw=black, line width=1pt,inner sep=2.7pt},
every path/.style={circle connection bar, fill=darkblue}]
  \SetVertexNoLabel
  \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
    \grEmptyCycle[RA=2/sin(60)]{5}
  \end{scope}
  \AssignVertexLabel{a}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \Edges(a0,a2)
  \Edges(a3,a1)
  \Edges(a4,a0,a3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is probably the best compromise between compactness and dependency cutting.

Comment: Yes, I think so, recalling I did try other parameters I can come up with.